# C++ get full path to file in directory

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program to set the wallpaper of the user to a file. I need to get the full path to the image file

Here is my code

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    FreeConsole();
    const wchar_t *filenm = L"hay.jpg"; //Get path to hay.jpg
    bool isWallSet = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 
    (void*)filenm, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would anyone here know where you stored the file on your machine? Why don't you just write the path in there yourself?

Comment: where is the image file stored in your system?

Comment: If the image is in the current working directory of the program, you can use `GetCurrentDirectory` to get the absolute path to that directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the file in question is within your current working directory, [`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sounds like a good idea. It takes a filename and converts it into a full path by prepending the current working directory.

Pay careful attention to the warning in the docs: you can't safely use this API in a multithreaded program, because the current working directory is saved as a process-wide global variable which isn't thread-safe to access.

Also be aware the API will return a path whether the file exists within the working directory or not; it just takes the filename you give it and prepends the current working directory.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  char filename[] = "test.txt";
  char fullFilename[MAX_PATH];

  GetFullPathName(filename, MAX_PATH, fullFilename, nullptr);

  MessageBox(NULL, fullFilename, "DEBUG", MB_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use Viual Studio 2015, you can use the new [filesystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986850.aspx) library for this.

```
#include <filesystem>
using filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;
  ...
  const wchar_t *filename = filesystem::canonical(L"hay.jpg").c_str();
  ...
```